# The Block Editor: Disable "Color settings" in the specific block

Tags: block-editor

The "Pull Quote" block comes with the "Color settings" option which is located in the sidebar.

[image]

I am aware that we can remove the style using `wp.blocks.unregisterBlockStyle` but is there a way to remove a specific control for a specific block.

In this case, I am wondering if it's possible to remove the "Color settings" option just for the "Pull Quote" block.

Comment: You could use the [`editor.BlockEdit` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit) to modify the block's `edit` component, which is [this](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/pullquote/edit.js) for the Pull Quote block; however, you should probably just clone the entire block and make it yours by editing the relevant parts, then unregister the default block and register your Pull Quote block.